# Need foreach to include folders and subfolders

Tags: php, upload, foreach, ftp

again , sorry for asking so many questions.
I currently have this code:

```
foreach (glob("black/*") as $filename)
```

problem is that it doesnt include folders inside the folder "black".
Any way to work that out?
Full code:

```
foreach (glob("black/*") as $filename)
 if(ftp_put($conn, $ftpFolder . basename($filename) , $filename, FTP_BINARY)) {
```

and then goes the response, 
Thanks in advance :)

P.S
My goal is that I want the script to upload whole bunch of files,folders and sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a recursive solution:

```
function print_files($dir){
    foreach (glob("$dir/*.txt") as $filename) {
        echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
    }
    // call recursively for every sub directory
    foreach (glob('$dir/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $subdirs) {
        print_files($subdirs);
    }
}
print_files("black");
```

**Disclaimer:**
 
It was written with Notepad - I can't test it...

Comment: Tried it out, Gives me as output the folder that I have under black and my .txt file in black/, doesnt show the txt file inside of the subfolder - black/test. btw - changed ur script to "$dir/*" because there will be lots of files to upload once I get this little thingy ready :)